# React-Native DisconnectableInputStream java exception

Tags: java, android, react-native

On fresh React-Native project, i would like run default app on Android device, but i've this Java Exception :

```
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.util.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:125)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at org.gradle.util.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:96)
        ... 1 more
```

The app has been run on device, but with **Error 500** on Metro Bundler.

Anyone can help me about this exception ? I'm on Linux environment.

Thank you community !

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a bundle for your app.

1. `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Then you could run it on your android.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By me this error comes up, because i had a bad file in the .idea folder.

found it as i tried to start the deployment server with

```
npm start
```

may this helps